# Angular material 2 mat-spinner strange transformation Safari zoom level 90% or lower

Tags: angular, safari, angular-material2

Good morning,

I have a bug for the mat-spinner in angular material 2. Viewing in safari when the browser zoom level is set to 90% or lower the spinner is off centered. B.n - the issue is worse at lower zoom levels e.g 50%.

I set the diameter to 40 but this has no impact on the issue.

```
  <mat-spinner [diameter]="40"></mat-spinner>
```

It seems that the spin is not centered only in Safari whereas Chrome and other browsers dont have the same issue.

Version of Safari - Version 12.0 (14606.1.36.1.9)

See stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-progress-spinner

Set the zoom level in safari lower than 100%

B.n - the spinner is also distorted at zoom levels above 100%

Comment: Could you attach a screenshot?

Comment: See https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-progress-spinner

Comment: I use safari from big Sur and it looks just fine. Can anyone check it out with an x86 safari?